android compose soft keyboard
I am trying to create a fully custom TextField in Android using Jetpack compose
everything is ok with the hardware keyboard but the soft keyboard is not opening
this is how I start:
(with simple code)

@Composable
fun MyCustomTextField() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    var hasFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .onFocusChanged { hasFocus = it.hasFocus }
            .focusable()
            .focusTarget()
            .clickable {
                // Request focus and show keyboard when clicked
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    focusRequester.requestFocus()
                } else {
                    keyboardController?.show()
                }
            }
            .onKeyEvent {
                if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
                    if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                            text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        text += it.nativeKeyEvent.unicodeChar
                            .toChar()
                            .toString()
                    }
                }
                false
            }
    )
    {
        Text("text:" + text)
    }


    // Request focus when the composable enters the composition
    LaunchedEffect(hasFocus) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
        keyboardController?.show()
    }
}


Try this `LaunchedEffect(hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {

        keyboardController?.show()

    }

}`


I tried this too. not worked
